# String.contains registering as !String.contains

Tags: java, append, delimiter

I'm trying to append any lines in a text file which contain a given set of strings. I created a test file, in which I put one of those strings. My code is supposed to print any line in the text file containing one of these strings on the same line as the previous line in the text file. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AppendIfFromFileScanner {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\frencke\\workspace\\Testing Stuff\\Append Tetsing\\file3.txt");
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String delima = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+&\\s+";
    String delimb = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\+\\s+";
    String delimc = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+z\\s+";
    String delimd = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+1\\s+";
    String delime = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+2\\s+";
    String delimf = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+3\\s+";
    String delimg = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+4\\s+";
    String delimh = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+5\\s+";
    String delimi = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+6\\s+";
    String delimj = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+7\\s+";
    String delimk = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+8\\s+";
    String deliml = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+9\\s+";
    String delimm = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+a\\s+";
    String delimn = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+b\\s+";
    String delimo = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+c\\s+";
    String delimp = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+d\\s+";
    String delimq = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+e\\s+";
    String delimr = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+f\\s+";
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scanner.nextLine());}
for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++){
    for(String s=null; i<lines.size(); i++){
        s = lines.get(i);
        if(!s.contains(delima)||
           !s.contains(delimb)||
           !s.contains(delimc)||
           !s.contains(delimd)||
           !s.contains(delime)||
           !s.contains(delimf)||
           !s.contains(delimg)||
           !s.contains(delimh)||
           !s.contains(delimi)||
           !s.contains(delimj)||
           !s.contains(delimk)||
           !s.contains(deliml)||
           !s.contains(delimm)||
           !s.contains(delimn)||
           !s.contains(delimo)||
           !s.contains(delimp)||
           !s.contains(delimq)||
           !s.contains(delimr))
        System.out.print("\r\n" + s);
        else if(s.contains(delima)||
                s.contains(delimb)||
                s.contains(delimc)||
                s.contains(delimd)||
                s.contains(delime)||
                s.contains(delimf)||
                s.contains(delimg)||
                s.contains(delimh)||
                s.contains(delimi)||
                s.contains(delimj)||
                s.contains(delimk)||
                s.contains(deliml)||
                s.contains(delimm)||
                s.contains(delimn)||
                s.contains(delimo)||
                s.contains(delimp)||
                s.contains(delimq)||
                s.contains(delimr))
        System.out.print(s);}
}
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("Cannot find file.");
}
}
}
```

The contents of my text file are:

```
first line
text     & append this line
```

So basically, I know that my text file has one of these strings (in this case, delima) in it. Yet, my output is:

```
first line
text     & append this line
```

Which is not supposed to happen. The output I want is:

```
first line text     & append this line
```

Does anyone know why it's interpreting the second line of my text file as though it does not contain delima, even though it clearly does? Any help would be appreciated. I'm fairly sure that the problem is something to do with my if statement, but I'm obviously not the expert here.

Comment: `contains()` **doesn't** take a regex!

Comment: It's that simple? Thanks!
EDIT: I tried replacing the regex with just a regular five spaces, &, and another space, and that didn't change my output. Does this mean that the only way to do it is to append every line with an ampersand?

Comment: This feels a little like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the underlying issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: `contains()` is basically assesing that the `String` you are looking for has an index in the text it's definition is `indexOf() > -1`

Comment: Just use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Comment: @DuncanJones, yes, it appears that it is an XY problem; sorry about that. I'm trying to append any line in a text file that contains any of those strings (delima, delimb, etc.) to the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.contains()` method matches an exact string, not a regular expression.

Instead, you may wish to try using [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). You may need to adjust your pattern to obtain similar behaviour to `contains()` (see [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) for some examples).

Comment: If I use String.matches(), won't that only append the strings that match delima exactly? Or is there a way to wildcard it?

Comment: @ItsanAlias Did you look at the page I linked to? It shows wildcard matching (hence I thought it was a sensible thing to link to).

Comment: I just did, thanks. I now have set String delima to ".*\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+&\\s+.*" but it is still not giving me a match. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh, I figured that out on my own. I hadn't changed all of my `s.contains` to `s.matches`. However, now I'm having a problem with my `if` statement. In my text file, I changed the `&` to a `+` to test `delimb`. It's reading `if(!s.matches(delima)||!s.matches(delimb)` etc. and since `!s.matches(delima)` returns true, it satisfies the `if` statement and prints s on a new line. How can I get it not to satisfy the `if` statement?

Comment: @ItsanAlias If you have a new question, please post it separately. Trying to trouble-shoot numerous follow-on problems in the comments doesn't normally end well!